# Confused by EOL while scanning string literal error

Tags: python

I'm getting an really confusing "EOL while scanning string literal" error when trying to run my code. The bit it's pointing at isn't on line 15, and removing line 15 doesn't help. There are no EOLs or reserved characters in the dictionary (checked in a text editor).

What on earth have I done?

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\myScripts\Quiz\quiz.py", line 15
    'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 'New
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

---

```
#! python3
# this code generates a random quiz for each member of a class

import random

capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix','Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver','Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee','Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas':'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine':'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri':'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh','North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City','Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence','South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee':'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont':'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia', 'West Virginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}

# creates 35 quizzes
for quizNum in range(35):
    # creates the files
    quizfile = open('statesquiz%.txt' % (quizNum + 1),'w')
    answerFile = open('statesquiz%_answers.txt' % (quizNum + 1),'w')

    # writes some stuff in quiz files
    quizFile.write('Name: \n\nDate: \n\n')
    quizFile.write((' ' * 20) + 'State Capitals Quiz (Form %s)' % (quizNum + 1))
    quizFile.write('\n\n')

    # shuffles states
    states = list(capitals.keys())
    random.shuffle(states)

    # loop through states and make a question for each
    for questionNum in range(50):

        # gets right and decoy answers
        correctAnswer = capitals[states[questionNum]]
        wrongAnswers = list(capitals.values())
        del wrongAnswers[wrongAnswers.index(correctAnswer)]
        wrongAnswers = random.samples(wrongAnswers, 3)
        answers = wrongAnswers + [correctAnswer]
        random.shuffle(answers)

        # writes more stuff in quiz file
        quizFile.write('%s. What is the capital of %s?\n' % (questionNum + 1, capitals[questionNum]))
        for i in range(4):
            quizFile.write('     %s. %s\n' % ('ABCD'[i], answers[i]))
        quizFile.write('\n')

        # writes stuff in answer file
        answerFile.write('%s. %s\n' % (questionNum + 1, 'ABCD'[answers.index(correctAnswer)]))

quizFile.close()
answerFile.close()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Try restarting your IDE/clearing caches. It seems to just be derping.

Comment: The code you've posted does not throw that error

Comment: My guess: your editor broke the code while applying line wrapping.

Comment: Ah. Thanks, I thought it seemed weird. I've just C&P from Atom to Notepad++ and now it's running!